# What is the meaning of this sentence "I don't think I'm getting through to you."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

Thanks and apologies for a silly question from a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb ["get through to"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-through-to) means to make someone understand.  So "I don't think I'm getting through to you" means I don't think you're understanding me.

A couple of quick examples:

1. That math teacher really got through to me.  I understand my mathematics studies better than ever!
2. I am getting through to him, despite his unwillingness to understand my point of view.

Perhaps what you're confusing yourself with is ["get through"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-through) which means to surpass or finish with difficulty.

Comment: @mark42inbound No problem.  Happy to help.  :)